# Arbitrary precision with inaccurate calculation?

Tags: precision, differential-equations

I am interested in the numerical solution of ordinary differential equations (ODE's) with a precision of 25 to 30 significant digits (I mean finding 25 to 30 significant digits of the actual solution at each point).

My first guess was multiple precision or arbitrary precision arithmetics.

However according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25714882/12067036) there are multiple precision packages that do  calculations without multiple precision (?!). This may not be as contradictory as it sounds. However it poses a severe problem.

So do there exist any multiple precision packages (in Fortran, C, C++, Python, Java or whatever) that can do reliable multiple precision computations?

Comment: Did you also read the other answers to that question that all pointed out how to get arbitrary precision from mpmath?

Comment: Well, yes. However, I am a Python begginer so I cannot be sure about it. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

Let's stay modest for demonstration purposes and aim for 20 correct digits in an implementation of the circle equations `u'=v; v'=-u` which give `u=sin(t)` for `(u0,v0)=(0,1)`. Let's integrate this over the interval `[0,1]`.

This has a Lipschitz constant of L=1, which makes arguing about step sizes easier. With the classical Runge-(Heun)-Kutta order 4 method, the global error is expected as some fraction of `h^4`, so to get about 20 digits after the dot, we need `h=1e-5`, which also means `100 000` steps over the interval. Each has some floating point errors in the last digit, so that over the full interval, possibly 5 digits will be unreliable. Thus the working precision should be 25 digits or more

```py
from mpmath import mp

mp.dps = 25

def RK4(t0, y0, tf, N):
    h = (tf-t0)/N
    u,v = y0;
    for n in range(N):
        k1u, k1v = v, -u;
        k2u, k2v = v+0.5*h*k1v, -(u+0.5*h*k1u)
        k3u, k3v = v+0.5*h*k2v, -(u+0.5*h*k2u)
        k4u, k4v = v+h*k3v, -(u+h*k3u)
        u, v = u+h*(k1u+2*k2u+2*k3u+k4u)/6, v+h*(k1v+2*k2v+2*k3v+k4v)/6
    return u,v

u,v = mp.mpf(0), mp.mpf(1)
t, dt = mp.mpf(0), mp.mpf(1)/10
for k in range(10):
    u1,v1 = RK4(t,[u,v],t+dt,10**3)
    u,v = RK4(t,[u,v],t+dt,10**4)
    t = t+dt
    # error estimate via extrapolation
    # u = uexact + uerr, u1 = uexact + 10**4*uerr
    uerr, verr = (u1-u)/9999, (v1-v)/9999
    with mp.extradps(5): si, co = mp.sin(t), mp.cos(t)
    print("t=%s"%t)
    print("u=%30s, sin(t)=%30s, step error=%30s"%(u, si, uerr))
    print("v=%30s, cos(t)=%30s, step error=%30s"%(v, co, verr))
```

giving a result list as follows

```
t=0.1
u=  0.09983341664682815230680593, sin(t)=   0.0998334166468281523068142, step error=-8.291772901773692681703852e-24
v=   0.9950041652780257660955634, cos(t)=    0.995004165278025766095562, step error=8.312005953404312840899088e-25
t=0.2
u=   0.1986693307950612154593963, sin(t)=   0.1986693307950612154594126, step error=-8.167351203006133449374218e-24
v=   0.9800665778412416311242006, cos(t)=   0.9800665778412416311241965, step error=1.654857583109387499562722e-24
t=0.3
u=   0.2955202066613395751052971, sin(t)=   0.2955202066613395751053207, step error= -7.9613619853238077687103e-24
v=   0.9553364891256060196423186, cos(t)=   0.9553364891256060196423102, step error= 2.46199127828304457142136e-24
t=0.4
u=   0.3894183423086504916662812, sin(t)=   0.3894183423086504916663118, step error=-7.675762243562770001241619e-24
v=   0.9210609940028850827985405, cos(t)=   0.9210609940028850827985267, step error=3.244534570708288054285545e-24
t=0.5
u=    0.479425538604203000273252, sin(t)=   0.4794255386042030002732879, step error=-7.313560501818737799847937e-24
v=   0.8775825618903727161163026, cos(t)=   0.8775825618903727161162816, step error=3.994583217701846864434659e-24
t=0.6
u=   0.5646424733950353572009052, sin(t)=   0.5646424733950353572009454, step error=-6.878230619815552707865177e-24
v=   0.8253356149096782972409814, cos(t)=   0.8253356149096782972409525, step error=4.704815938714571792025104e-24
t=0.7
u=   0.6442176872376910536725712, sin(t)=   0.6442176872376910536726143, step error=-6.374164848843117446876767e-24
v=   0.7648421872844884262558976, cos(t)=     0.76484218728448842625586, step error=5.368009690718806448531807e-24
t=0.8
u=   0.7173560908995227616271302, sin(t)=   0.7173560908995227616271746, step error=-5.806451504735070057940143e-24
v=   0.6967067093471654209207975, cos(t)=     0.69670670934716542092075, step error=5.977494663044775070749797e-24
t=0.9
u=   0.7833269096274833884613378, sin(t)=   0.7833269096274833884613823, step error=-5.180615155476414729415392e-24
v=    0.621609968270664456484775, cos(t)=   0.6216099682706644564847162, step error=6.527225370323768115169452e-24
t=1.0
u=   0.8414709848078965066524596, sin(t)=   0.8414709848078965066525023, step error=-4.503113625506337452188567e-24
v=    0.540302305868139717401006, cos(t)=   0.5403023058681397174009366, step error=7.011939642161084587215687e-24
```

One can see that the errors are restricted to the last 4 digits, as expected. The cumulative method error is about `1e-23` over each of the sub-intervals, thus in total less than `1e-22`, about the same as the expected floating point noise, which in sum of the quasi-random rounding or arithmetic operations will influence at maximum 5 digits, on average about half of that.

---

Higher order methods will allow larger step sizes, thus less steps, which not only reduces the computation time but also the accumulation of rounding errors. Thus requiring less additional digits for the working precision, which also reduces (slightly) the computation time.

For heavy computations like this, one should use a compiled language. The strong typing and transitioning from garbage collection to active memory management will make the code look less easy to read, like in the code cited in [How are the trigonometric functions tested in the GNU C Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38213584/3088138)

Comment: Which combination of (compiled language) + (multiple precision package) is best suited for windows 10?

Comment: I can't really say, for number crunching there is not much difference between languages. Object oriented is halfway to scripting languages in ease-of-use, but it might be more difficult to prevent memory bloat. gmp is well-established and has bindings to most languages. Pari/GP is a combination of multi-precision math/CAS library and scripting interface, I'm sure in the relevant wikipedia pages there are more libraries. Again, for basic arithmetic as required in RK4 etc. they should all be equivalent.